# Click autocomplete support for windows?

Tags: python

I was reading `https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/bashcomplete/` and it doesn't seem like there is a way of getting this working on Windows. Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know if you can get something like this for CMD, but I had a teacher once who used a bash terminal inside windows.

Answer (score 0):

According to the page you linked:

> Bash, Zsh, and Fish are supported

By default Windows has CMD and Powershell, though if you use something like [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to get a Linux terminal, there's no reason that software that works with one of the aforementioned terminals wouldn't work on Windows.

If you're writing software for non-developer Windows users though, you're out of luck.